# mapOf() vs emptyMap() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Just started using Kotlin in our projects. To initialise an immutable map or list (possibly any collections in Kotlin) I could see two options `mapOf()` and `emptyMap()` (`listOf()` and `emptyList()` for a list).

Basically, the `mapOf` is nothing but an inline function that returns `emptyMap()`.

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <K, V> mapOf(): Map<K, V> = emptyMap()
```

What is preferred over another and why does Kotlin expose both?

Comment: I'm guessing empty map is static reference to an empty map for initializing, to prevent unnecessary allocations; while mapOf is a factory method for initializing map with some initial values. You probably do ctrl + click on emptyMap() in intellij and see the source.

Comment: `emptyMap()` is more verbose than `mapOf()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [specialized overload](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.5.20/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L42-L64) of `mapOf(vararg Pair<K, V>)` - there is no need to perform the size check if you're calling that function without any arguments.

As for "what's preferred over another" - whatever makes the code it's used in more readable. Performance-wise, there's no difference (as `mapOf()` is inline), though for the sake of consistency you might want to choose one and stick with it.